# How can I convert git branches to remotely tracked ones?

Tags: git, github

We have just converted a bunch of our *SVN* components to *Git* using `git svn clone` The layout for our components consist of a *trunk* and a 1 or more *branches*.

After the migration and pushing everything to *GitHub* and running `git branch -a` we get:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/1.0
  remotes/origin/1.1
  remotes/origin/1.10
  ...
```

However up on *GitHub* under *branches*, we can only see one *master*; We need all those branches to also be pushed over.

Looking at the following [issue](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1171) it seems that my local branches must be converted to *tracking branches*.

How can I achieve this easily considering that some of our legacy components have hundreds of branches?

Comment: try this command: git push --all origin

Comment: It doesn't work it says: "Everything is up-to-date"

Comment: I saw you have a remote branch origin/1.0, but do not have a matched local branch.How run 'git checkout 1.0' says?

Comment: `git for-each-ref --shell --format='git checkout --track -b %(refname:strip=3) %(refname)' refs/remotes/origin/` will generate a list of commands, remove HEAD and master from that list

Comment: Thanks @PiotrSkotnicki, I managed to fix it in an alternative way but I will remember your solution for future.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that all I had to do was actually checkout each of the branches first which would output:

```
Branch foo set up to track remote branch foo from origin
Switched to a new branch foo
```

Then all I had to do was execute:

```
git push --all origin
```

Thanks to both [@banking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2659843/banking) and [@Piotr Skotnicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3953764/piotr-skotnicki)

All of my branches now appear under *GitHub*.